# What does 'housing dedicated' mean in context of microprocessors?

Tags: meaning-in-context, technical

So, recently I came across an article, which reads:

> With the newer FPGAs housing dedicated processors, it
>   is worth exploring how applications currently implemented
>   solely on ECUs can be virtualized across the two resources

FPGA being  Field-Programmable Gate Array, if that's important. 
And the thing I don't seem to get is that 'housing dedicated' part. What should that mean? The article is by no means about houses or anything like that, quite the contrary, it's all about embedded systems in electric cars.

Comment: It's "housing (dedicated processors)".  Look in the dictionary for "housing" (as a verb) and "dedicated" (as an adjective).

Comment: (It helps to know that "dedicated processor" is a "thing".)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The verb *to house* means something like "to contain". So these are new FPGAs which now contain dedicated processors. A "dedicated" computer component means something like a separate component with that specific function (i.e. a separate CPU), rather than just part of a SoC or similar (a SoC does many other things besides CPU things).

Comment: Just to be a bit more specific, "dedicated", in this case, would mean part of the circuitry that is dedicated to being a processor, unlike the rest of the array which can be configured to any function (including a processor). I think *housing* is a terrible choice of word, here. It took me a couple of goes to parse it.

Comment: @JamesRandom - "Housing" is perfectly idiomatic tech-speak.

Comment: @HotLicks: By that you mean computer speak? Even so, it is ugly.

Comment: @Cerberus - :)) :)) :))  Nerd-speak is never "ugly".